# Embedding $U^* \otimes V^*$ into $(U \otimes V)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Define $\phi : U^* \times V^* \rightarrow (U \otimes V)^*$ by $$\phi(f,g) = H_{(f,g)}$$ where $H$ is a linear extension of $h_{(f,g)} : \{u \otimes v | u \in \mathcal{B}, v \in \mathcal{C}\} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}, h_{(f,g)}(u \otimes v) = f(u)g(v)$ when $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ are fixed bases for $U, V$ respectively.

Then $\phi$ is a bilinear map. So by Universal Mapping Property of the tensor $(U^* \otimes V^* ;b)$, there exists unique a linear map $T : U^* \otimes V^* \rightarrow (U \otimes V)^*$ satisfying $$T(u \otimes v) = \phi((u,v))$$ for any $(u,v) \in U^* \times V^*$.

$\textbf{Claim:}$ $T$ is injective.

Let $x = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i, f_i \in U^*, g_i \in V^*$ such that $$T(x) = 0.$$ Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n H(f_i, g_i) = 0$$ that is, $$\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(u)g_i(v) = 0$$ for any $u \in \mathcal{B}, v \in \mathcal{C}.$

How to use this information to deduce that $x = 0$ ?

Please notice that there is no assumption about $U, V$ finite dimensional.

Comment: what is the definition of $\mathcal{F}?$

Comment: It just an underlying field of $U, V$

Answer (score 3):

We can assume the $g_i$ are linearly independent (otherwise rewrite $x$ as a shorter sum). For any $u\in U$ we have
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^nf_i(u)g_i=0
$$
in $V^*$. Thus $f_i(u)=0$ for each $i$. Since $u$ was arbitrary, $f_i=0$ for each $i$.